# Compare NSMutableArray elements to find second largest from list

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray

I'm trying to find the second largest number in an array. Why is this code not working?

```
NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@5,@25,@48,@2,@52,@53, nil];
id temp,larg2;int k=0;    

while(k<2)
{

    for(int j=0;j<5-k;j++)
    {

          if( [array1 objectAtIndex:j]>[array1 objectAtIndex:j+1])
        {
            temp=[array1 objectAtIndex:j];
            [array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:j+1]];
            [array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:j+1 withObject:temp];
        if(k==1  && j==3). //this statement is not running??
        { larg2=temp;
            NSLog(@"The answer is %@",larg2);
        }
        }
    }
    k++;

}

   NSLog(@"The value of Second Largest Element is %@",larg2);

}
```

How do I find the second largest element?

Comment: Could not find second largest element????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a NSSet before if you need to exclude duplicates then Sort the array descending, pick the second element.

```
NSArray  * unsortedArray = @[@22,@11,@53,@15,@7,@37,@11,@92,@84,@5];
NSSet *numberSet = [NSSet setWithArray: unsortedArray];
NSArray *sortedNumbers = [[numberSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO] ]];
NSNumber *secondHighest;
if ([sortedNumbers count] > 1){
        secondHighest = sortedNumbers[1];
    }
NSLog(@"%ld", secondHighest);
```

Without sorting :

```
NSInteger max1 = -1, max2 = -1;
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < [unsortedArray count]; ++i) {
      if ([unsortedArray[i] integerValue] > max1) {
          max2 = max1;
          max1 = [unsortedArray[i] integerValue];
       } else if ([unsortedArray[i] integerValue] > max2 && [unsortedArra1y[i] integerValue] < max1) {
            max2 = [unsortedArray[i] integerValue];
       }
    }
NSLog(@"%ld %ld",max1, max2);
```

If you have small set of array then you can use sorting method to sort an array but for the large number of element it will take more time with increase in numbers with very poor in performance O(n^2) and second method is simple and performance O(n).

Comment: Your answer and mine are quite similar. However, the system sort methods like sortUsingDescriptors tend to do better than O(n^2) performance. Typically they give O(n log n) performance, with O(n^2) as the worst case. Also, the descriptor-based methods tend to be slower than the comparator-based methods like `sortedArrayUsingComparator` since they're built for very general-case sorting and use KVO to extract the values from the array elements. With comparator-based methods you can write code that compares the values of the array elements directly without the overhead of KVO

Comment: Yes. You are right  `sortedArrayUsingComparator'` takes n-1 comparisons and each element is involved in comparison at most  log n times.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh, Siddhesh's "Without sorting" is working code for the best solution. If you want copy/paste code, use that.

Comment: I have to submit an assignment so did yesterday as u told without swapping and change large number by passing.Thanks Duncan & @Siddesh Mhatre..!!!

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Oh great. We're helping you cheat on a school assignment!

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to sort the array if all you need is the 2nd largest item, and the sort algorithm you're using is very poor (It has O(n^2) performance, which means it will get slower with the square of the number of items, so that with just a few hundred items it will start to take a long time to complete, and with a few thousand items it will seem to hang.)

Thus there's no real point in trying to debug your code. It's "putting lipstick on a pig" as the expression goes.

Instead of sorting the array, do a single pass through the array. Set a variable `largest` and `secondLargest`. If the current array entry is bigger than largest, check to see if `largest` is bigger than `secondLargest`, and replace `secondLargest`, then replace `largest` With the new largest value. That will give you O(n) performance (time to completion goes up linearly with the number of items in the array) which is faster than the fastest sort algorithms, and also a lot simpler to implement.

If you don't care about performance, just use a system sort method, then take the 2nd to last item in the sorted array. The system's sort functions are optimized, and typically have O(n log n) performance, which is quite good for sort algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@20,@12,@24, nil];
NSSet *tempSet = [NSSet setWithArray: arr];
NSArray *arr1 = [[tempSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES] ]];
NSLog(@"%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:1]);
```